# Fusioncharts Timeseries

Tags: fusioncharts

Currently I am running into an issue in FusionCharts where TimeSeries view is inaccurate  when using min or max aggregation on step-line graphs.  While the data when zoomed in is accurate, upon zooming out the data becomes warped and inaccurate.  Currently I can not find anything in the documentation about force limiting the zoom so that users are unable to zoom out to a distorted view. While the features of the chart are great, the distortion is to the level that it renders the chart useless.  Does anyone know a way to limit the zoom out function to a max time range or increase the amount of points shown on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binning feature available in FusionTime.
Read more about it here: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusioncharts-aspnet-visualization/components/fusiontime-components/fusioncharts-net-binning

Comment: Please do not only post links as answers but provide a summary of the link content to avoid information loss if the linked website goes offline

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts allows you to plot a huge set of data along with the interactive zooming, panning and scrolling features. With FusionCharts you can easily zoom into any subset of data, pin a certain data point and pan to compare with the rest of the data.

To know more about it - https://www.fusioncharts.com/features/zooming-and-scrolling

Data Aggregation & Binning - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusioncharts-aspnet-visualization/data-engine/aggregation#max

```
    Aggregation aggregateMax = new Aggregation {
    "Sales", Aggregation.Function.MAX
};
DataModel maxValue = model.Aggregate(aggregateMax);
```